# Learning about type methods/type properties

Tags: swift

I'm reading through the Swift documentation about type methods and type properties, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it says this particular thing (in bold):

> Within the body of a type method, the implicit self property refers to
>   the type itself, rather than an instance of that type. **For
>   structures and enumerations, this means that you can use self to
>   disambiguate between type properties and type method parameters, just
>   as you do for instance properties and instance method parameters.**
>
> More generally, any unqualified method and property names that you use
>   within the body of a type method will refer to other type-level
>   methods and properties. A type method can call another type method
>   with the other method’s name, without needing to prefix it with the
>   type name. **Similarly, type methods on structures and enumerations
>   can access type properties by using the type property’s name without a
>   type name prefix.**

So, why is this pointing out structures and enumerations being able to do these things when, as far as I know, you can do these things with *any* kind of type methods/parameters (i.e. classes as well)? It makes me think I'm missing something.

The page in the documentation I'm looking at is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

Comment: Seems like a documentation bug, since classes act the same way in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I wasn't the only one with this question. I'm not sure how I didn't see this post before: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276962/static-properties-and-implicit-self-property-in-structures-and-enumerations-vs